# Good ways to secure yourself on Reddit and other social media sites?

Tags: privacy, vpn, anonymity

I would like to prevent websites like Reddit from having access to information about my devices, my IP, personal information, etc. I have began using Nord VPN and cleared my cache on both safari and Chrome for Reddit, downloaded a new browser, Opera, etc. What are some other useful tips for preventing a website from tracking your IP and knowing who you are?

Comment: How is NordVPN knowing your IP any safer than Reddit knowing your IP?

Comment: Consider using Tor or Tails.

Comment: Why don't you first identify and figure out what information are you trying to protect and from there ways to safe guard.

Comment: Don't use your real name and picture on a site like StackExchange. :s

Comment: Cheers to whoever gave me the links for the duplicate, would reddit's process be similar to the sites discussed in that thread?

Comment: @MechMK1 because I trust them more. Simple as.

Comment: @VipulNair IP, DNS and system info. I don't want them to know what type of device, browser, IP etc.

Comment: @TomK. Probably shouldn't, but just made the account using facebook for all the stack sites, so.

Comment: @NathanSmithJr. Deleting Facebook is probably a big step in the right direction :upside_down:

Comment: @J.J One day, for now I'm more concerned about Reddit. Any tips for that particular site?